# how to prove the divisibility?

Tags: number-theory, congruences

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and prime $p$ i was asked to prove that $p$ divides $\binom{n}{p}$ -$[n/p]$. Where $[\text{...}]$ denotes box function and $\binom{n}{p}$ denotes $n$ choose $p$.

Can not understand where to start from. Is it possible by congruency? Please help.

Comment: What is $nCp$?? Is it $\binom{n}{p}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes. I'm not sure what the "box function" is though.

Comment: Yes. N choose p i.e. n!/(p!×(n-p)!).

Comment: Box function is the greatest integer function. i.e. greatest integer less then or equal to the given value or parameter

Answer (score 0):

By Lucas's theorem $\binom{n}{p}$ is congruent to $\binom{w}{1}$ where $w$ is the second digit in the base $p$ expansion of $b$ ( because the base $p$ expansion of $p$ is just $10$). So $\binom{n}{p}$ is congruent to $w$ and $w$ is clearly congruent to $\lfloor n/p\rfloor$

Comment: Actually i dont know Lucas' theorem. I am  in class 11. Can u explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas's_theorem ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Lucas's theorem is more general than what is needed for this problem, and  a student at grade 11 would have to prove Lucas' theorem first to then prove this problem; that is probably not the easiest way to do it.

Comment: why the downvote? Has anyone seen a proof of Luca's theorem? It is direct and does not pass through the proof of this problem at all.